# sys.objects column [Type] weird value 'ST'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, datatypes, metadata

I am seeing a strange (not-documented) value for [Type] column in sys.objects. The value is "ST" as shown in the below (note, dbo.Record is a user table)

Does anyone know what this 'ST' value means? (This is in SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition)

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Similar question was posted to MSDN forums back in May: [What is Type = ST in sys.objects?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/066b934f-36e5-4c9f-a1c1-d362dace66d6/what-is-type-st-in-sysobjects?forum=sqlgetstarted). And, that one also relates to SQL Server 2014. No answer there, though :-(

Comment: Are you using any optional product features which might be relevant?

Comment: i have run into this tyoe as well, in SQL Server 2017.  When I ran a check across all DBs on the servers, there were hundreds of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't know what ST stands for, but based on the naming convention I would have to guess it's some kind of system-generated statistic.

You could check to see if there is, by chance, some kind of text associated with the object if it is a module, e.g.:

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(613577224);

SELECT definition FROM sys.all_sql_modules
  WHERE object_id = 613577224;
```

You could also try:

```
EXEC sp_help N'dbo._ST_OEA33...';
```

Finally, you could try to brute force discover this object in any of the catalog views. This script tries to find any view that contains a row where the `object_id` column is equal to that value.

```
CREATE TABLE #v(v sysname);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'', @obj int = 613577224;

SELECT @sql += N'INSERT #v 
    SELECT DISTINCT ''sys.' + name + N''' 
      FROM sys.' + QUOTENAME(name) + N' 
      WHERE [object_id] = @obj;'
  FROM sys.all_views AS v
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM sys.all_columns AS c
      WHERE c.name = N'object_id' 
      AND c.[object_id] = v.[object_id]
  ); 

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@obj int', @obj;

SELECT v FROM #v;

DROP TABLE #v;
```

If this yields nothing, you could expand it to include all `int`-based columns across all catalog views, since sometimes `object_id` values are stored in columns with different names, like `referenced_major_id` or `parent_object_id`, and any results here might yield clues as well.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #v(v sysname);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'', @obj int = 613577224;

SELECT @sql += N'INSERT #v 
    SELECT DISTINCT ''sys.' + v.name + N''' 
      FROM sys.' + QUOTENAME(v.name) + N' 
      WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' = @obj;'
  FROM sys.all_views AS v
  INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS c
  ON v.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
  WHERE v.[schema_id] = 4
    AND c.[system_type_id] IN (56,127)
    AND v.name NOT IN (N'syscolumns')
    AND v.name NOT LIKE N'dm_fts_%'; 

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@obj int', @obj;

SELECT v FROM #v;

GO
DROP TABLE #v;
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I will give some run later and report back. But object_definition() and select * from sys.all_modules return either null or nothing. I also expect this is something to do with statistics, according to statistics naming convention, _WA_xxx means "Washington", _ST_ may means SEATTLE ? :-)

Answer (score 3):

ST Objects are Database Table usage Statistics. I was in a situation yesterday were we needed to delete a Schema completely on an [Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/azure-sql/sql-managed-instance/?cdn=disable). On trying to drop the schema, we were unable to do this, and got some long Error like ST__xxxxxx___Chinesechars..... The reason for this is the tables that were dropped now no longer belonged to a schema and their Statistics still existed in the Managed Instance sys tables.

You have 2 options.  Try to drop the statistics before dropping the table using:

```
DROP STATISTICS [Database].[Schema].[Table];
```

Or move the statistics to another schema.  Not the best, but will get you around the error when dropping a schema.

```
ALTER SCHEMA [SchemaToMoveTo] TRANSFER OBJECT::[SchemaFrom].[ST__xxxxxx___Chinesechars]
```

Seems to be a bug within SQL Managed Instances.

Comment: What are "Database Table usage Statistics"?  Only thing I am aware of with this sort of info are DMVs that are in memory structures only and don't create entries in `sys.objects` AFAIK